# duvida com tag select

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select

Tenho a seguinte tag select:

```
<!--select-->
                        <div class="uk-form-row">
                            <div class="uk-grid">
                                <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                    <div class="uk-input-group">
                                        <span class="uk-input-group-addon"><i class="uk-input-group-icon uk-icon-male"></i></span>
                                        <label>Pessoa</label>
                                        <select required class="md-input" ng-options="item as item.t0053_descricao for item in itemsContas track by item.t0053_id_conta" ng-model="selectedContas"></select>
                                        <span class="uk-input-group-addon">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="cursor:pointer !important" ng-click="getAllContas()" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:'right'}" title="Atualizar Colaboradores"><i class="material-icons md-48">refresh</i></a>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--fim select-->
```

o resultado é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de colocar um input dentro do select, para que o usuario possa digitar para pesquisar, como poderia fazer isso no meu codigo ?

Comment: Coloca esse plugin https://select2.github.io/examples.html e se quiser stilizar veja a documentação é facinho! abs

Comment: Adriano, obrigado pela dica, era bem o q eu queria. Abraço